# How to add JOI validator to firebase function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform

How to add JOI validator to firebase function as a middleware? I call firebase function like below:

```
exports.createUserAccount = region("europe-east1").https.onCall(createAccount); // createAccount is an function
```

in normal endpoints/routes in express i do something like this:

```
app.post("/app/some/endpoint", auth(), validator(), createAccount());
```

where my `validator` is an Joi middleware where I check that `req.body` is correct like a provided schema.

PS. I don't have an `(req, res)` in `createAccount` function, cause firebase return provided in this function an simple dto.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can use JOI middlewares on Firebase by exposing an Express app via HTTP triggered functions and via Callable functions.

`onRequest` and `onCall` both takes a function that will return a Promise. Starting from here, you can create an Express application, register any middleware you want, then pass the Express app to the onCall.

The way to create the Express app is greatly documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events). Note that there is a big difference between onRequest and onCall:

- onRequest expose the whole Express app, so you can register routes and so on, and build a REST API using it;
- onCall will wrap your Express app, because the SDK calls it with a POST request. It means you'll have to only accept one request on your Express app, mapping it to the root path and expecting a POST request.

Comment: So I can't so this with using `onCall`?

Comment: I've just checked the source code of the Functions' SDK. It turns out it is possible for onCall functions too. I'm going to update my answer

Comment: @GregorioPalamà can you update the answer for onCAll

Comment: @rbansal I already updated it for onCall. previously, I wrote it is not possible, but then I've checked and it turned out that is possible, with the difference that onCall wraps the whole Express app. Let me know if you need an example

Comment: @GregorioPalamà It will be great if you can provide an example. I am trying to understand the working but not able to figure it out.